# how to pass optional flags to pre-tasks using Python invoke?

Tags: python, invoke

I am using [Invoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org/) and have two tasks: one cleans a raw data file to produce a clean data file, and the other produces several plots from the clean data file:

```
RAW_FILE = "raw.csv"
CLEAN_FILE = "clean.csv"
PLOT_FILE = "plot.svg"

@task(optional=["logging"])
def clean_data(c, logging=None):
    """Produce cleaned-up dataset."""
    print("CLEAN", logging)
    _configure_logging(logging)
    df = clean_raw_data(RAW_FILE)
    df.to_csv(CLEAN_FILE, index=False)


@task(pre=[clean_data], optional=["logging"])
def plot_data(c, logging=None):
    """Create plots of data."""
    print("PLOT", logging)
    _configure_logging(logging)
    make_plot(CLEAN_FILE, PLOT_FILE)

def _configure_logging(log_level):
    """Initialize logging."""
    if log_level is not None:
        print("SETTING LOGGING TO", log_level)
        CONFIG["LOGGING_LEVEL"] = log_level.upper()
```

If I run:

```
$ invoke clean-data --logging info
```

then logging is set to `INFO` and I get a message from inside `clean_raw_data`. However, if I run:

```
$ invoke plot-data --logging info
```

then:

1. `clean_data` is invoked with `logging=None`, so no log message appears.
2. `plot_data` is then invoked with `logging="info"`, so its log message appears.

My expectation was that command-line flags would be passed down to dependent tasks. I tried doing this manually:

```
@task(pre=[call(clean_data, logging=logging)], optional=["logging"])
def plot_data(c, logging=None):
    ...as before...
```

but this produces an error message because `logging` isn't defined at the point the `@task` decorator is invoked.

Is there a way to chain optional arguments in the desired fashioned?

Comment: Found a workaround using an extra task to set logging (see https://gvwilson.github.io/nitinat/dependencies.html) - is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: Hello, how did you solve it> the link is out and I cannot see the workaround that you used